# How to call .click() when retuning to index.html from another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a portfolio site and have a sliding nav on index.html which contains a group of projects with links leading to other work.html pages once an  element is clicked on the nav in the header.

What I want to do is when returning from a work.html page to the index.html page, is auto open the sliding nav automatically.

Thanks a lot if you can help!

document.querySelector(".work").click()

works with opening the sliding nav, but I don't know how to only run this when returning from one of the projects or work.html pages

this is the nav on the index.html and work.html pages

```
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link work" href=# onclick="openNav();showButton()">work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="...">experience</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="..." rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">about</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When returning to index.html '.work' will automatically open

Comment: Please provide your question with a [MCVE]. What have you tried so far to get this to work?

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to answer you: do all the pages open in the same tab? What does openNav do? how do you "return from one of the projects or work.html pages", to your index.html? If it's a basic link, you could add a parameter to the URL like `index.html?openwork=1` and test against it

Comment: you return by clicking an <a href= index.html> tag in the nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    if (document.referrer.indexOf('work') > -1) {
    //Perform required operation
  }
});
```

`document.referrer` gives the previous URL.

Comment: This is working, I just have to figure out how to stop it for opening the nav when first visiting the page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React try putting the function in componentDidUpdate(). If you are using only JS no framework, try keeping a list so you know from where the user is coming on to your index page. Use window.location for that. Might not be the best approach, but play with it see what happens